# App Domain: not a valid domain. Site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: dns, facebook-oauth

I have a domain at http://qotr.net that I'm trying to set up as an app so that I can use OAuth. It *was* set up a few weeks ago, and we just now finished implementing the OAuth hooks on our application, when Facebook started giving us errors.

Now, when I go to the settings page, and edit anything, I get:

Error
App Domain: qotr.net is not a valid domain.
Site URL is not a valid URL.

I have: `qotr.net` for the app domain and `http://qotr.net` for the site url.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fqotr.net

Tells me that it can't parse qotr.net. The site is clearly up and usable, and Google OAuth works.

I can't find anything online on why it might not parse correctly; any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in the App Domain, enter your site domain without the http:// or the www.  Just put in, say for my website iamzang.com

For the site URL below the page, enter http://iamzang.com/

That will do the trick. I got the same error before and with this the domain is no longer invalid.

Comment: Tried that; same problem, debug tool shows the domain as invalid.

Comment: APP Domain - enter your domain with www or http. Ex. google.com
site URL - now include http or www. That should work. It did for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a platform first. There you enter the full domain, e.g. http://www.yourdomain.com.
Then set the App Domain to yourdomain.com!

Answer (score 0):

On facebook app registration page, under Settings -> Basic -> Basic Info try entering both domains in the App Domains space  (with and w/o www)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write anything in the App Domain under "Basic Info". Instead under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" click on the check: Website with Facebook Login, which will give you a space to write in your website url (http://qotr.net).

Answer (score -2):

I just got this working by using 'domain.com' in the App domain field & 'http://www.domain.com' in the Site URL field.
Hope that helps.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other answer, that doesn't work; the debug tool is showing the domain as invalid.